# What's difference between Penrose Arc Decoration and Ammann Line Decoration for tiling kite and dart?

Tags: tiling

Penrose Arc for edge tiling rule

[image: Penrose Arc for edge joining rule]

Ammann line for edge tiling rule

[image]

The result seemingly the same. It could be use to join the tile to be penrose tiling. So what is the difference between these two method? I try to look for detail but only could conclude that Ammann decorated line is somehow **stronger rule** or something like that. Is it true and why it is?

Answer (score 1):

They give the same tilings, but the decorations are highlighting different aspects of the global structure of the tilings (radial vs rotational structures, which are essentially orthogonal to one another).